# How to sandbox untrusted monitor driver

Tags: drivers, vnc, screen-sharing, sandbox

I am considering getting an e-ink monitor ([Dasung Paperlike Pro](http://dasungtech.com/)) due to eyestrain.

It looks like [installation on macOS requires disabling of System Integrity Protection](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/paperlike-world-s-first-e-ink-monitor-13-3#/comments). I'd like to avoid that.

Is there a way to use this driver safely? I'm happy for the hardware to have full read-only access to the contents of my screen, but nothing more.

My idea was to install the driver into a *virtual machine*, and give that virtual machine the HDMI and USB that connect to the monitor.

The missing piece is: **how do I mirror the contents of my host machine's screen into the virtual machine?**

VNC would work, but I'm wondering if there's a less intensive way. For example letting my virtual machine read the host machine's graphics buffer or similar. Failing that: what's the cheapest protocol for screen sharing (i.e. when there are no bandwidth constraints)?

The core of this question is *efficient screen-sharing to a VM*, but I am also interested in any input regarding how to investigate / sandbox the behaviour of [the macOS driver](http://www.dasung.com/sta/zh_cn/software_cnpaperlikepro.html).

Comment: Sounds like a whole lot of work to save a 2 minute job - disable SIP, install, enable SIP.

Comment: even after I re-enable SIP, I believe that the driver retains its privileges. if it's malicious, I don't want it to have kernel-level privileges.

Comment: If you think the driver may be malicious, you don't want it at all, anywhere.